# Is there a way to create square viewfinder in Expo's BarCodeScanner?

Tags: react-native, expo

As the title implies, how can I set the viewfinder of the Expo's BarcodeScanner to be square-shaped?

I'm referring to this document here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/#usage

I've tried setting the width and height of the barcode scanner to be equal and the result is still not a square.

```
 <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.qrScanner}
 />

// styles
qrScanner: {
width: 200,
height: 200
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: My bad attempt is to create a box over it and use zIndex to cover a full-screen viewfinder (not a good solution tho)

PS. I'm not sure why but I cannot use react-native-camera in an expo project